# SQL Server: Receive notifications when Job Schedule is completed

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, notifications

We have a Job Schedule with 5 steps that runs daily overnight and we want to know whether it succeded or not as well as how many rows were updated and inserted.

Is there a way we can do this?

Comment: There is a tab for notifications in the properties of the job itself

Comment: Though the notification won't tell you how many rows were updated. You'll need to get that information within the job itself and use DB Mail.

Comment: Hello @Larnu. How can I get the information within the job itself?

Comment: `@@ROWCOUNT` would be one way.

Comment: Great! So for each step using rowcount I would need to send an email? Or is there a way to save the rowcount for all tables and send an email?

Comment: You can `INSERT` it into a table yes.